# Schema Changes after Dataframe Data insert into MySQL Table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mysql-workbench

I am new to Spark SQL,

I am using DataFrame which has schema as below

```
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName[0], DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName[1], DataTypes.StringType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName[2], DataTypes.DoubleType, true));
fields.add(DataTypes.createStructField(fieldName[3], DataTypes.StringType, true));
```

I am Overwriting the data into MySQL, MySQL Schema shown as below.

```
Field[0], VARCHAR(20)
Field[1], VARCHAR(20)
Field[2], DOUBLE
Field[3], DATETIME
```

whenever data is written in MySQL table, it over write the schema to Text, Text, Double, Text.

I don't want schema should be change, it should insert the data without changing the schema of table in MySQL, Please suggest.

I am using spark-core_2.10 version 1.6, spark-sql_2.10 version 1.6

I have tried casting the values but didn't work

```
DataFrame intoSql;
intoSql.selectExpr("cast(Field1 as java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) Field1");
intoSql.selectExpr("cast(Field2 as java.sql.Types.VARCHAR) Field2");
intoSql.selectExpr("cast(Field3 as java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP) Field3");
intoSql.write().format("TableNameinMYSQL").mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url, tableName, Properties);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set [`truncate` option](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter@jdbc(url:String,table:String,connectionProperties:java.util.Properties):Unit)

> `truncate (default false)`: use TRUNCATE TABLE instead of DROP TABLE.
>
> In case of failures, users should turn off truncate option to use DROP TABLE again. Also, due to the different behavior of TRUNCATE TABLE among DBMS, it's not always safe to use this. MySQLDialect, DB2Dialect, MsSqlServerDialect, DerbyDialect, and OracleDialect supports this while PostgresDialect and default JDBCDirect doesn't. For unknown and unsupported JDBCDirect, the user option truncate is ignored. 
>   to `true`

```
intoSql.write()
  .option("truncate", "true")
  .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
  .jdbc(url, tableName, Properties);
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help, even after using .option("truncate", "true"), schema of MySQL has change from 
Field1, varchar(20) 
Field2, varchar(20) 
Field3, double 
Field4, datetime
to
Field1, Text
Field2, Text 
Field3, double 
Field4, Text

Comment: Maybe this was/is a bug in the Spark version you used. I had the same problem with Spark 2.2.0 and it looks like with Spark 2.3.1 this option actually does work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with MetadataBuilder and createTableColumnTypes attribute as shown in this test case https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/jdbc/JDBCWriteSuite.scala#L454 ?